Prove that a displaced thermal state evolves into a displaced thermal state
Considering the physical model of a harmonic oscillator at frequency $\omega_0$, which interacts with a heat bath at temperature $T$. The relevant Hamiltonians for this model are given as
\begin{equation}
    H_S = \hbar \omega_0 a^{\dagger}a, \hspace{10pt} H_B = \sum_j \hbar \omega_j a_j^{\dagger}a_j, \hspace{10pt} H_{SB} =  \hbar \sum_j i g_j (a + a^{\dagger}) (a_j - a_j^{\dagger}) 
\end{equation}
Where $H_S$, $H_B$, and $H_{SB}$ denote the system, bath, and system-bath interaction Hamiltonians.
The master equation for the harmonic oscillator, coupled to heat bath under Born- Markov approximation, can be found to be
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial \rho_S}{\partial t} = -i \omega_0 [a^{\dagger}a, \rho_S] - k(1+n_0)(a^{\dagger}a\rho_S - 2a\rho_S a^{\dagger} + \rho_S a^{\dagger} a ) -kn_0(a a^{\dagger} \rho_S - 2 a^{\dagger} \rho_S a + \rho_S a a^{\dagger}) 
\end{equation}
Where $
        k = \pi \sum_j g_j^2 \delta(\omega_j - \omega_0), \hspace{10pt} n_0 = \frac{1}{e^{\beta \hbar \omega_0} - 1} $ are dependent on the properties of the bath.
I need help to prove that an initial state of harmonic oscillator of form  $ \rho(0) = (1-f(0)) D(\alpha) e^{-\beta(0) a^{\dagger}a}D^{\dagger}(\alpha)$ will evolve again into a displaced thermal state under the given master equation.
This physical model and master equation can be found in the book Quantum Optics by G.S. Agarwal.

What have you tried? Show your work.

I was trying to calculate the expectation values of relevant parameters (for example, \alpha) using this master equation, but that doesn't seem to work.
